# How to not have seekBar set to 0 when next song is played

Tags: java, android, runnable, seekbar

I would like to have the `mediaplayer` play the next song, and have the seekbar continuously go forward. However, right now the seekbar resets back to 0 when the next song is played.

How would I have the seekBar not reset back to 0 when the next song is played?

Here is my `onCompletion` method:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  mp.release();
  if(currentTrack < tracks.length) {
    currentTrack++;
    if (currentTrack >= 2) {
      currentTrack = 0;
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, tracks[currentTrack]);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    if (currentTrack > 0) {
      mp.seekTo(tracks[currentTrack]);
    }
    handler.post(UpdateSongTime);
    mp.start();
  }
}
```

Here is the thread that updates all of the positioning:

```
private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if(mp.isPlaying()) {
      startTime = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
      seekBar.setMax(songEndTime);
      int currentSongEndTime = songEndTime - mp.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
      startTimeText.setText(convertSeekLength(startTime));
      String endTime = "-" + convertSeekLength(currentSongEndTime);
      songDisplay.setText(songArrayList.get(currentTrack).getTitle());
      endTimeText.setText(endTime);
      seekBar.setProgress(startTime);
      handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a solution myself that involves creating an `Arraylist of mediaPlayers` instead of just making `one mediaPlayer`.

Here is the working code if anyone needs it:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  for(int i = 0; i < currentTrack; i++) {
    trueSeek += mediaPlayers.get(i).getCurrentPosition();
  }
  currentTrack++;
  if(currentTrack >= mediaPlayers.size()){
    currentTrack = 0;
  }
  handler.post(UpdateSongTime);
  mediaPlayers.get(currentTrack).start();
}
```

and the thread:

```
private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if(currentTrack == 0){
      trueSeek = mediaPlayers.get(currentTrack).getCurrentPosition();
      startTime = trueSeek;
    }
    if(currentTrack > 0){
      int tempSeek = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < currentTrack; i++){
        tempSeek += mediaPlayers.get(i).getCurrentPosition();
      }
      trueSeek = mediaPlayers.get(currentTrack).getCurrentPosition() + tempSeek;
      startTime = trueSeek;
    }
    seekBar.setMax(songEndTime);
    int currentSongEndTime = songEndTime - trueSeek;
    startTimeText.setText(convertSeekLength(startTime));
    String endTime = "-" + convertSeekLength(currentSongEndTime);
    songDisplay.setText(songArrayList.get(currentTrack).getTitle());
    endTimeText.setText(endTime);
    seekBar.setProgress(startTime);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when next song is play that time set `seekBar.setProgress(0);`